# How to remove "Report URL" from emailed PDF reports header?

Tags: email, civireport, reports

I would like to remove the link from a report email header. Is it easy to achieve? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be hardcoded (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Report/Form.php#L3405), but you could use [hook_civicrm_alterMailParams](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterMailParams/) and do something like (untested - you might have to adjust the regex):

`if ($params['groupName'] == 'Report Email Sender') {
  $params['html'] = preg_replace('/^Report URL.*$/', '', $params['html']);
}`

Another option which is maybe simpler is just completely replace the html in the hook, if you don't really need the other text either:

`if ($params['groupName'] == 'Report Email Sender') {
  $params['html'] = 'Insert your own html';
}`